# How to implement google adsense in codigniter

Tags: google-ads-api

```html
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>`<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"></ins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store google adsense code in common view file and load it in required view page(s).

For example, save adsense code in adsense.php view file and call it in required files using below code

```
<?php $this->load->view('adsense'); ?>
```